# How to set time in datetime field in extjs or sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4.1

I need some help ,
My question is that.. is there any option to set time also with date in extjs datetime field. please look below image.
herer is my code for datetime picke.

```
{
      {          xtype: 'datefield',
                fieldLabel: 'Posted At',
                //labelWidth: 140,
                format: 'd-M-Y H:i',
                flex: 1,
                name: 'postedAt',
                allowBlank: false,
                value: new Date(),
                listeners: {
                    scope: this,
                    select: function (f, v) {
                    }
                }
            },
```

[image]

Comment: You want time to show time in date dropdown ?

Comment: yes. I want time to show time in date dropdown

Comment: Atleast in extjs this thing is not possible.You need to find another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext.picker.Date doesn't support that, so we have to write custom component.

[Here](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?137242-Ext-ux-DateTimeField-DateTimePicker-for-ext4-also-DateTimeMenu-TimePickerField) you can find the realization for ExtJS 4.1.0 and 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the arguments of Date() in javascript. May be the below code is a hint for your answer.

```
             {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                fieldLabel: 'Posted At',
                //labelWidth: 140,
                format: 'd-M-Y H:i',
                flex: 1,
                name: 'postedAt',
                allowBlank: false,
                value: new Date(2017,4,23,12,00,00,0),
                listeners: {
                    scope: this,
                    select: function (f, v) {
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Dude read his comments what hi is saying.He wants time in date dropdown not in text field.

Comment: @Tejas Is there any config option for this control?

Comment: No there is no config.You will need to create any custom component for it as mentioned in one of the answer.